# Javascript chained promise only processing one of the promise's

Tags: javascript, promise, vuejs2

I have a Javascript chained promise that only processes the `question` promise. The `progress` promise works when the `question` promise is noted out.

What would I need to change to process both promises?

```
nextQ: function(item){

        var percentQuestion = 100/this.numberQuestions;

        var progress = new Promise(
          function (resolve, reject) {
            console.log(percentQuestion);


          var elem = document.getElementById("myBar");

          var numericWidth = elem.style.width.replace(/\D/g,'');

          var currentWidth = +numericWidth;

          var newWidth = +numericWidth + +percentQuestion;

          var id = setInterval(frame, 10);
          function frame() {
            if (currentWidth >= newWidth) {
              clearInterval(id);
            } else if(currentWidth < 100){
              currentWidth++;
              elem.style.width = currentWidth + '%';
                }
                else{
                  console.log('max');
                };
            };
            resolve();
            }
          );

          var question = new Promise(
            function (resolve, reject) {

              var newKey = item + 1;

              var y = document.getElementById('question' + item);

               var x = document.getElementById('question' + newKey);



                if( y.style.display === 'block'){
                       y.style.display = 'none';
                       x.style.display = 'block';
                       console.log("Changed");
               };
               resolve();
              }
            );

                Promise.all([progress,question]).then(function () {
                    console.log('processed');
                })
                .catch(function (error) {
                    console.log(error.message);
                });
      },
```

Comment: You are abusing Promises in this code ... as it stands, the Promises make no sense at all, they are simply resolved to `undefined` immediately

Comment: This code doesn't really need Promises.. there's no asynchronous code anywhere that uses promise. The "frame" function is executed by setInterval, but it doesn't have resolve or reject in it

Comment: This is frustrating as I originally didn't use promises but another user said I would need them. Thanks for your input

Comment: perhaps you do need them, for example, in `progress` to resolve once `currentWidth >= newWidth` - if so, move the resolve in to that if block - however, the code you've posted is not clear on this at all - there is also no indication when the `question` promise should be resolved